# How to properly model biased photodiode circuit with cross-talk

Tags: circuit-design, photodiode, transient-suppression, crosstalk

The overall goal is the following: I need a board with two photodiodes, each with a bias tee (cutoff around 70 MHz) connected to it, for a total of 4 outputs. The photodiodes will see short pulses, resulting in ~2 ns long 50 mA peaks.

I had originally simulated the circuit and tweaked it until I had something that seemed acceptable (the LTspice schematic with all symbols can be downloaded here: https://mega.nz/file/Qock0ICY#JAr3I45PXIqwudYJaXH65Ub3blWNn5s_WYlmVUCB1IA):

[image]

You can see the two copies of the circuit: The top path in each case is the AC port, the bottom path the DC port. I put a RC low-pass filter after the inductor to reduce the ripples (which also works, according to the simulation at least). The bias voltage (12 V) is shared between the two photodiodes. For the bottom circuit, I replaced the photodiode with a current source and a small capacitor (for the photodiodes capacitance) to be able to simulate it. R5 and V1 are simply there to accelerate charging of the low-pass filter.

The simulation predicts small residual ripples on the DC1 port, and (unsurprisingly) nothing on AC2 & DC2:

[image]

However, after getting the board manufactured, I see ripples on all outputs, even if only one of the photodiodes is illuminated: With a ~2 V signal on the AC port of the bias tee of the illuminated photodiode, I see <10 mV ripples on the DC port of the same bias tee (similar to the prediction of the simulation), <10 mV ripples on the second DC port and ~30 mV ripples on the second AC port. The latter two are completely unexpected.

I have two main questions:

- How could I improve the model to predict the ripples?
- What is causing the ripples in the first place, and how can I fix them?

## Update 3

Here's a screenshot of the schematic for the PCB:
[image]

## Update 2

Here's a screenshot of the PCB. Please note that the labels to not match the ones from LTspice. A rough overview:

- Apart from a 6.8 uF & 100 nF decoupling capacitor on the 12 V supply rail, the circuit on the PCB is exactly what's in the LTspice simulation.
- Power connector is on the right (J5)
- One photodiode + bias tee is on the top half of the board, the other on the bottom half (with the decoupling capacitors for the 12 V rail in between)
- The left connectors are the DC paths, the right ones for the AC path.
- For scale: The board is 20x20 mm

[image]

## Update

I also ran an AC sweep (without the transmission lines, as those led to errors...), and stuff up to 1-2 GHz is reasonably suppressed:

[image]

I have also tried to replace the 1 MΩ resistors on the DC paths (R2/R7) with 50 Ω resistors to match the impedance of the transmission line: As far as I can tell, it did not affect the magnitude or shape of the ripples at all.

Comment: The mis-matched transmission line **T2** presents frequency-dependent reactances to your (intended) low-pass filter for the "DC-path". Very difficult to predict the resultant frequency response, especially if you properly model the parasitic properties of L1, C2, C3, C4. No doubt, at some frequencies, some AC will sneak through - I suggest you do an LTspice AC sweep of frequencies between 10MHz and 10GHz.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for the suggestion! I added a AC sweep to the question, and I also experimentally tested a 50Ohm termination instead of 1MOhm for the two DC paths: Apart from the expected reduction in the DC level, I could not notice any difference. In particular, the ripple shape & magnitude seem to stay the same. I am also not sure how that would lead to cross-talk between the channels?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but 50 mA is an enormous current from a diode small enough to be only 3pF. I'd be worried about it's reliability. I have seen monitoring photodiodes on short pulses laser systems ablated when laser power was not correctly attenuated. Hopefully you are accounting for maximum power and heat?

Comment: Your spice model doesn't reproduce the crosstalk, so obviously it is omitting the source of the crosstalk. Show the schematic and layout of your board (which do include those things) and then maybe someone can infer what the missing model components are.

Comment: @user1850479 The photodiode is producing around 1-2V output, which should be perfectly safe in our experience, so I have no concerns there. (The 50mA might be slightly over-estimating the actual current). And thank you for the suggestion regarding the PCB, I have added a screenshot now (the schematic is effectively what I added to LTSpice, so I didn't include a second screenshot there)

Comment: The bias voltage looks to be directly shared between the devices with no filtering and no decoupling, so there will be crosstalk. You could simulate it by putting a resistor/inductor between your photodiodes to simulate that trace. But really instead of simulating it, just add decoupling.

Comment: You should also post a schematic since it is hard to follow that board layout. There may be other issues.

Comment: @user1850479 Thanks! To your comments: I added the schematic for the PCB, hope it's easier to follow now. Adding a small inductance & resistance after the 12V supply does indeed reproduce the cross-talk in the simulation (so far, I failed to include the capacitance of the photodiodes in my thinking, leading me to erroneously conclude that the bias voltage is not important for the final result). Do you have any suggestions for how to best achieve the required decoupling? Would it be enough to add a separate set of capacitors very close to the two photodiodes, or do I need something in addition?

Comment: @user1850479 Small update: I checked for cross-talk on a board with the second photodiode removed: The ripples on the outputs of the removed photodiode are still the same, so it looks like the main contributor to the ripples is not the 12V line, or at least not via the capacitance of the photodiode. So as you said, there must be other issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to pull an enormous photocurrent through one diode, but you have them in parallel and with no decoupling.  When that intense pulse of light hits a diode, it suddenly allows a huge amount of current to pass, which pulls down the voltage across both diodes.  In addition they're physically very close and you have no dedicated ground plane, so when large transients in current pulse through the system you may induce voltages on the other lines as well.  Finally, since the diodes are so close and your light so intense, you are almost certainly going to have optical cross talk.

Things I would do:

**Add decoupling**.  That 6.8u in parallel with 100nF was meant to be the decoupling for one photodiode, but you didn't use it like that.  When you added the second diode you should have duplicated it.  They also need to go directly across the photodiodes to provide current and prevent noise from leaving that part of the circuit.  I would consider possibly using multiple 10u per diode in parallel since biased at 12v their effective capacitance will be much lower and leaving out the smaller 100nF as well.

**Split the bias voltages**.  If you're really planning on 10s of mA of current, and need very low crosstalk using two separate bias lines is reasonable.  I have done ~10mA of photocurrent in arrays and see several percent crosstalk even with spacing and lots of decoupling.  As you go higher it will get larger.  If you don't want to do that, try putting a resistance between the decoupling capacitors and the 12v supply, one per line.  Larger resistances will provide better isolation, but they'll also limit your photocurrent.

**Make the board larger, add a ground plane and move things apart**.  Optical cross talk from the pulse hitting one diode and then scattering off the metal housing to the other is going to happen.  Similarly you'll get electrical crosstalk because you have intense pulses on wires that are very close together without a real ground plane.  You can fix all of these things by moving the diodes further apart, switching to a 4 layer board, not routing signal lines over/near other lines and adding a baffle or separator between the diodes to block light.

As for SPICE, it has probably taken you as far as it can now that you're thinking about trace inductance and optical scattering.  Figure out how much crosstalk you can tolerate and then make whichever of the above changes you think are worthwhile until you get it down low enough.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions! It's great to have some concrete things to improve, now I'll just have to see how much of these I can successfully implement